How can I get a production server alert log in my Slack channel?, so that if there is a problem I will be notified as soon as possible
Current Situation:

Our production server experiences frequent downtime due to:

High CPU loads (100%)

Uncaught exceptions causing crashes



Lack of visibility into API behavior leads to:

Delayed issue identification relying solely on user complaints

Increased downtime resolving problems after they occur




Impact:

Downtime disrupts user experience and damages our reputation.

A reactive approach to troubleshooting is inefficient and leads to further downtime.

The lack of API behavior monitoring hinders proactive problem detection and preventative measures.



Desired Outcome:

Implement a system that proactively sends alerts to a designated Slack channel for production server issues, including:

High CPU usage

Server crashes

API errors



Gain real-time visibility into API behavior to identify and address potential problems before they cause downtime.

Achieve faster reaction times to production server issues, minimizing downtime and improving user experience.



Backend Monitoring can be easily done by the Wooffer. Here by implementing the Below steps, you can achieve more future than a description of the question.
Step 1 : Install
npm i wooffer

or
yarn add wooffer

Step 2 : Setup ENV
token = "<Your Token>";
serviceToken = "<Your Service Token>";

Note : get your token and Service Token from https://app.wooffer.io/
Step 3 : Add Wooffer to Root directory


const wooffer = require("wooffer");
const express = require("express");

wooffer(process.env.woofferToken, process.env.woofferServiceToken);

// Add this code to track endpoint usage(Optional)
const app = express();
app.use(wooffer.requestMonitoring);



Now You can track

API Usage
Logs
Bugs
Real-time Usage
Resource Usage

Some Images for reference





I am using this in my project and its work amazing for me

Using Slack Bot alert you can solve this problem
here I made a global function for slack alert


const axios = require("axios");
exports.responseInClientSlack = async (body) => {
  try {
    return await axios.post(process.env.SLACK_URL, body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};



After Define this global function you can use in your node JS project
I have you this in global error handle function
Here is example of this code


 responseInClientSlack({
        attachments: [
          {
            title: `error`,
            text: `\n\nstatusCode: ${err?.status} \n\nMessage : ${err?.message}\n\n stack: ${err?.stack} \n\n user:${req?.user?.id}`,
            color: "#FF0000",
          },
        ],
      });



For set webhook inside slack and get SLACK_URL you can prefer this you tube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxtC40gUS2A

This Work Fine But. Does it send a notification after their server crashes?

No this is not possible in this code
I think you need 3rd party monitoring service for this
https://wooffer.io/  can you plz check this once ?

Thanks for Sharing wooffer it's Realy work for me
